# How to gag a snout without tape or muzzles?

Tags: vocalizations

Long snouts are hard to gag. Unlike the great roundness of the human head, a snout is narrow and has a monotonous cross-sectional area that is excellent at getting binding to slip. Tape can alleviate these issues, but it isn't present in many worlds, including the one I'm asking about. Furthermore, muzzles, while they can be quite effective in the real world, are far too specialized to be carried by the average kidnapper

Given this, could a snouted being be gagged using ropes and other such bindings, without needing muzzles or tape?

Comment: When I think of a gag I think of a thing that goes between the teeth.  It seems to me a long muzzle would be easy to gag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive tourniquet should do the job, made from piece of rope or leather and a stick or metal bar to twist it. If snout isn't extremely bony it should dig itself in without sliding and stop snout from opening. If snout isn't very hairy, using extremely abrasive material is ideal, it would hold itself in place even better and cause pain when trying to slide or rip it off, deterring creature from doing so. Amount of time needed to use it is not ideal but well trained kidnapper could be very proficient with it, since it's a very simple tool.

Answer (score 2):

Crocodilians have very strong muscles to shut their jaws, but weak muscles to open them.  Thus it is rather easy to hold the jaws of cocodilians shut while handling them.

Putting a noose over the snout or wrapping a rope around it several times is usually  enough to keep the croc's mouth closed. You should look up videos of handling or moving crocodilians to see how their jaws are kept closed.

The question asks about kidnapping a snouted being.  That sounds like kidnapping an intelligent being, a person, instead of rustling an animal.

If the being being captured is a person, the kidnappers can put a gun to their head or a knife to their throat and threaten to kill them if they make a sound.

I am not certain you know how to gag someone.

Gag - verb:

> : to restrict use of the mouth of by inserting something into it to prevent speech or outcry

Gag - noun:

> : something thrust into the mouth to keep it open or to prevent speech or outcry

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gag

So a gag is often a cloth thrust into the open mouth and tied behind the head.  So long as your snouted aliens walk upright and have their snouts in the same horizontal position as human mouths, gagging them should be similar to gagging humans.  There should be a broad back of the head opposite the snout to tie the gag.

In movies, bad guys often sneak behind someone and put their hand over their mouth to stifle their crys as they grab them.

I suggest that you try keeping a human mouth closed - using willing subjects, of course.  You could put thour thumb under their lower jaw and an finger on the bones of their nose and try to hold their mouth sut while they try to open it.

And you could try wrapping our hand around the snout of a dog you have good relations with and who won't mistake it for an attack.  See if the dog can open their jaws while you have your hand around their snout.

If thse tests succeed in keeping the mouths shut, you can assume that one of the alien kdnappers can sneak up behind their victom and put one hand around their snout while grabbing them with another hand.  If several persons cooperate in the kidnapping, they can soon have the victim bound, and then gag them like a human is gagged or else tie something around their snout.